# Ubuntu 13.10 Catalyst Installation

Tags: graphics, fglrx

On my Ubuntu 13.10 I use a Radeon HD 5730 / 6570M (supported) and AMD/ATI Mobility graphics controller (Linux kernel 3.12).

I can't make it work in any way, I always get black screen at login. It doesn't matter what procedure I follow. I have to purge `fglrx` and roll back to open source drivers.

I've tried everything in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI.

Also no success with Catalyst Control Center downloaded from http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install.

When I start the download, a popup says *Downloaded driver file contains errors*.

Is it simply impossible to install proprietary drivers on 13.10, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This works on mine with kernel 3.11 with latest 13.2 Amd catalyst already dowloaded:

```
sudo apt-get purge dh-make dh-modaliases execstack libqtgui4 lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 dkms

sudo apt-get purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle

cd Downloads/AMDCatalyst/.

unzip amd-catalyst-13.200-0ubuntu1-linux-amd64.zip

sudo sh amd-catalyst-13.200-0ubuntu1-linux-amd64.run

sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can with Beta drivers. They are the only one that should support Xorg version 1.14. Thank you for your answer! :D

Comment: After trying to install in this way I got an error concerning building kernel modules. Searching the internet i found a known bug with Kernel 3.12 and tried to solve it as described in comment #5 [link](http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=944) I ended up, as usual, with a black screen at login and i had to uninstall fglrx through live-cd. As i am still running on open source drivers, may I have some problems after I removed **dh-make dh-modaliases execstack libqtgui4 lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 dkms**?